# Why was 'I identify as someone with autism' an answer in the SO Survey 2018?

Tags: discussion, survey-2018

I have some feedback on the 2018 survey.

"I identify as autistic / a person with autism"

Why can we still identify as autistic, did I miss a memo where a mental disorder is somehow something I can identify as such? Is it to keep continuity from the original questionnaire? And if so, why is the "/ a person with autism" part added while it was not in the question?

I'm mostly confused about this, but also annoyed. Stuff like this contributes to false ideas about how autism and other disorders function or manifest. It implies choice, there is none.

My main reason to repost this issue (since I reported this in the original feedback question as well) is that the results still include the "I identify as autistic". In addition, there has been a change which now devalues the questionnaire in my opinion. The answer now includes "a person with autism". AFAIK: this was not in the original question, and may be perceived as a skewed result.

Can we please leave the option of choice out of the Survey 2019, and if an answer is possible, why was it an option in the first place?

Comment: completely agree,  this is a medical disorder and must be treated and respected with seriety, it's not a choice.

Comment: I would suspect that the reason for the wording is that Autism has the problem is that it's an ambiguously defined term.  It's used to indicate that a series of various symptoms have reached a given severity.  There's often a lot of subjectivity of both how severe a given person's symptoms are, and also how severe they need to be before it's defined as "autism".  While there will be some people that will be unambiguously having severe enough symptoms, or unambiguously not having them, there is certainly a range where different doctors would come to different conclusions.

Comment: Are you against having a question about being autist in general or is your request about the formulation "I identify as"?

Comment: @BDL I fully support the question regarding autism or other medical conditions, I strongly condemn the idea that anyone has a choice relating to autism. If anyone has any problem with answering this personal question, he or she can choose not to anyway.

Comment: @Servy Changing the 'I identify as' to a 'I experience symptoms that would imply autism' or something would be a welcome change of wording. As I might have not stated that clearly, my main issue with the wording is the implication of choice.

Comment: _"I identify as"_ is quite different from _"I identify myself as"_.

Comment: I identify as a purple unicorn.

Comment: @RobertColumbia and even though I do not agree with your chosen identity, I will defend your right to do so.

Comment: The golden rule applies: do not disclose anything you are uncomfortable with sharing with a company who's primary business model is marketing the data they collect on their site visitors.  They do have a business case for this, admittedly sledgehammery question, autism tends to be a desirable trait for a programmer but they often have trouble getting through the interview.  A backgrounder [is here](https://www.fastcompany.com/3062835/microsoft-autism-hiring).

Comment: *It implies choice* I disagree that it implies choice though I don't think I've seen that phrase used for a condition before.

Comment: I wonder if the awkward wording and use of the word "identify" in contrast to the other disorders has anything to do with the perennial person-first vs identity-first debate that's unique to the autism spectrum.

Comment: @Roberrrt: "I am on/identify with the autism spectrum"

Comment: @BoltClock would remove any of my complaints.

Comment: Being borned with this or that sexual organs is not a choice either, but doomed be the person to dare suggest we should not be able to answer "I identify as [whatever]". Either go against all of these "not choices", or don't.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier You're mixing up sex and gender.  One's gender is not about the organs you were born with.  Of course, many people would also argue that one's gender isn't a choice either, and that they didn't *choose* to be transgender, but rather that was simply how they are.

Comment: Imagine people who suppose to put together next survey ... specific wording over every little thing because someone might find it offensive / (or, and, if, foreach, for, GoTo) may not like it ...

Comment: @Veljko89 welcome to the world of today.

Comment: Well, if they're putting time and effort in the wording anyway, why not give them some feedback on it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We asked all of our demographic questions in a fairly similar way. For this question that references autism, we're making it clear that we're concerned with how *you* describe *yourself*, which is why we used an identity-focused framework. It's not at all intended to imply choice.

Comment: This is highly exaggerated, but why can’t I identify as a blind person then?

Comment: I’m being overly annoying now though- I just think the current wording gives out the wrong signal.

Comment: @Roberrrt: The Deaf community would like to have a word with you...

Comment: @Roberrrt: "*why can’t I identify as a blind person then?*" Some people can. Blindness is not binary; people are declared "legally blind" who can still see to some degree. Whether they identify as "blind" or not is at least partially up to how they deal with their senses.

Comment: @Roberrrt That's fair enough. In that question, we wrote "Which of the following describe you, if any?" Perhaps identity-focused responses are better there, too. For the question that references autism, I did a lot of research into how to best refer to autism and people with autism. Autism advocacy groups are mixed on how to approach it: some felt that "autistic" was best; others thought "person with autism" was best. I tried to be as inclusive as possible, but there's always room for improvement, though. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your research, and value your input, I might disagree on the wording, but this answers the ‘why’ part of my question.

Comment: @Kristina Lustig: Heh, I was right!

Comment: @NicolBolas I was mirroring this to the survey.

Comment: @Roberrrt: Yes, and I'm pointing out that the mirror works exactly the same way for blindness as autism.

Comment: Ah, I see, I misread.

Answer (score -3):

I think the question is vague. What is it differentiating *against*?

- Is the point of the question to differentiate people who identify as a "person with Autism" versus those who identify as "Autistic" (or "Aspie", etc.)?
- Is the point of the question to differentiate people who feel that they fulfill the diagnostic criteria for Autism from those who feel that they do not?
- Is the point of the question to differentiate people who have received a formal clinical diagnosis of an Autism condition versus those who have not received such a formal diagnosis?

Is the question intended as a *linguistic* survey? Is it intended to solicit *medical* information? Is it intended to classify people into *social* categories?

Comment: If the purpose of the question was to differentiate between these ways of phrasing things, why would the same question include *both*? Clearly, the purpose of the question is to not restrict people based on how they choose to refer to that aspect of themselves. The "/" should be read as "or".

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Not to mention the fact that it's juxtaposed as a single option against things like "I have a mood disorder", "I have an anxiety disorder", and "I have a concentration and/or memory disorder". Really not seeing the ambiguity here.